# How can we send a jsp page as json from a servlet.?

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

What I am trying to achieve is given below.

I have a jsp page **A.jsp**  with a form.
When I will click on submit on **A.jsp** some details will be sent to **ServletA via ajax.**
After servletA looks into the request parameters from A.jsp it will **either send an error message as string or if everything is correct send B.jsp.**

The jquery on  A.jsp will receive the response and change the innerHTML of a div of A.jsp with B.jsp if successfull
or show error message on top of A.jsp.

I am having problem understanding if the servlet is sending an error message or B.jsp .

Currently I do this in servletA

```
request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", errormsg);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/common/B.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

I will get the B.jsp as response in jquery which I can update as innerHTML. Also errormsg is printed in B.jsp .

But I want to send just errormsg to jquery / or just b.jsp to jquery and Identity on jquery side which is coming so that I can decide 
if I need to update just the error div with error msg or the whole div with B.jsp 
How can I achieve this ?

I thought of json and sending both in key value pairs like { 'errormsg':'invalid', 'responsetext':'html output of B.jsp after comilation" }
That way I can check if errormsg is present and then decide if only errormsg should only be update or whole div with html from b.jsp.

Here I do not understand how I can put

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/common/B.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

output to a json attribute.

**Please note :**

I cannot just send page names and then redirect from jquery. I need to send the whole page from servlet.

I cannot use any frameworks just servlet / jsp

Comment: What if you got the address in a header that contained `/WEB-INF/pages/common/B.jsp`and then made another AJAX call to grab the actual HTML page based on the location you received. You may then output the HTML page into the div.

Comment: @WilliamCallahan If I am doing it in two ajax requests, then it is easy as I can fetch validation message from from first servletA and if no errors get B.jsp from servletB.

Comment: @WilliamCallahan But I cannot do that as I am converting a project to  work via ajax with bootstrap and changes to java code should be minimum. So splitting each servlet to two is out of question. Like I said now I got it working by send B.jsp always with or without error embedded. This way I have to update the whole div even just to show error message. I was thinking if there is way to identity if error is present so that i just need to update errormsg div